# Use variable outside a $.get function

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having problem using variables outside a $.get function, the variable isn't found and the script stops.

What can I do?

```
$.get("../ajax.php", function (data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    test = json['jquery']['test'];
});

alert(test)
```

UPDATE: (This solved my problem)
I get the json with $.get. And pass it to my function and the json will be able to get later in the script.

```
$.get("../ajax.php", function (data) {
function(data) {                    
    loadApp(data);
});

function loadApp(data) {    
    json = JSON.parse(data);                
}
```

Comment: Please search before asking a question. This has been asked **so** many times previously.

Comment: Because `test` is in local scope.First declare it globally.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question I only find "hard ways" of doing it. Don't see the real logic in how to use them easy outside the function.

Comment: Read this to clear everything up... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @Kim there is no way to use it outside the function. Any code reliant on the result of the AJAX request must be placed in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a asynchronous call, all processing will have to be made in the callback function. Put your `alert(test)` inside the callback function instead.

**EDIT:**

```
$.get("../ajax.php", function (data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    test = json['jquery']['test'];

    alert(test); // Needs to be processed in this scope
});
```

This occurs since the JavaScript processor reads line by line, detects the ajax-call and sends it, it then jumps to the `alert`, which will try to alert a non-existing variable. Even if you declare it gobally it wont work; since the AJAX-return is asynchronous, and will therefore be executed in parallel to the other code.